# Unwanted Animation occurring

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I asked this question recently but did a poor job of presenting the problem. I am re-stating it here with the hopes of getting some help.

I'm writing a card app and animate the cards moving at certain points. At a certain point in my code, I am getting some unwanted animation with cards moving when they are not supposed to.

The animation in my app comes from the following code:

playersCards is an Array of UIImageView

```
 func moveCardUpDown(cardNum : Int, moveUp : Bool) {
    let moveCard = playerCards[cardNum]
    var moveInc = 0

    // -20 = Move Up, +20 = Move down
    if moveUp {
        moveInc = -20
    }
    else {
        moveInc = 20
    }

    //Animate the card
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        var newCenter = moveCard.center
        newCenter.y += CGFloat(moveInc)
        moveCard.center = newCenter
    }, completion: { finished in
        //print("Card Moved")
    })
}
```

The above code, when called moves the desired cards the way that I want them to
be moved.

I then try to just put images into the dealer’s cards  using no animation, (dealerCards is also an array of UIImageView).  The unwanted animation that occurs is that cards in the player’s hand are moved whenever the line of code below is executed.  The line is of course in a loop but even if I just execute the line once it does the same thing and cards in the players hand get moved. cardImage is a valid String holding the name of a card.

```
dealerCards[i].image = UIImage(named: cardImage)! as UIImage
```

Comment: Perfect explanation but unfortunately not enough code is provided for anyone to get an idea of what the problem is. The first snippet of code provided, can you show more of it? Is it inside of your viewDidLoad for example?

Comment: Thanks Dan, I have edited the question to include the entire function where the animation is done.

Comment: When is the `moveCardUpDown` function being called?  The only way I can see that `dealerCards[i].image =` would trigger your animation is if you've added a `didSet` to `image` on a `UIImageView` subclass.

Comment: So `dealerCards` is an array of UIImageView? How are those image view positioned? Are you using constraints (auto layout)? If you replace an image view's image with an image of a different size, the image view can change size and this can move other image views that are constrained to it. Can you make a minimal project demonstrating the issue and post it so it can be downloaded and run?

Comment: Also, if you claim or believe that the unwanted animation is because `moveCardUpDown` is being called, it's easy to prove that that is or isn't true: put a breakpoint on it. If it's being called unexpectedly, you'll pause at the breakpoint and you can see the call chain and you'll know _exactly_ why it is being called. If it isn't being called, your citation of `moveCardUpDown` is a red herring.

Comment: Is autolayout involved?  My sniffer says yes. I can explain how to stop this unwanted Not animation. Just let me know

Comment: What is newCenter?  If its data type is CGPoint, then why aren't you setting the x value?

Answer (score 0):

After a week or so of pulling my hair on this one I have found the problem.  You must uncheck the use of Auto Layout on the Mainstoryboard.

[image: File Inspector for Mainstoryboard]

Here's a link to an old answer to the same problem: http://www.raywenderlich.com/17811/how-to-make-a-simple-mac-app-on-os-x-10-7-tutorial-part-13/smat-disable-autolayout